# Popular tabela com api fluent

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho esse modelo **Muitos pra Muitos** e preciso popular a tabela através do arquivo **Seed** conforme descrito no final do post usando a **api fluent**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Arquivo context:**

```
public EfDbContext() : base("EfDbContext") { }
        public DbSet<TBUsuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TBMenu> Menus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TBPerfil> Perfis { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TBUsuario>().ToTable("TBUsuario");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TBPerfil>().ToTable("TBPerfil");

            modelBuilder.Entity<TBMenu>()
                .HasMany<TBPerfil>(p => p.Perfis)
                .WithMany(m => m.Menus)
                .Map(pm => 
                        {
                            pm.MapLeftKey("TBMenuID");
                            pm.MapRightKey("TBPerfilID");
                            pm.ToTable("TBMenuPerfil");
                        });
        }
```

**Seed:**

```
protected override void Seed(Lamar.Dominio.Repositorio.EfDbContext context)
        {
            var perfil = new List<TBPerfil>
                {
                    new TBPerfil {PerfilID=1, Nome="Administrador" },
                    new TBPerfil {PerfilID=2, Nome="Operacional" }
                };
            perfil.ForEach(s => context.Perfis.AddOrUpdate(p => p.PerfilID, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var menus = new List<TBMenu>
                {
                    new TBMenu{TBMenuID=1, Action="#", Controller=string.Empty, Icon="fui-user", Nome="Cadastros", Posicao=0, Tooltip="Cadastros" },
                    new TBMenu{TBMenuID=2, Action="Index", Controller="Clientes", Icon=string.Empty, Nome="Clientes", Posicao=1, Tooltip="Clientes" }
                };
            menus.ForEach(s => context.Menus.AddOrUpdate(p => p.TBMenuID, s));
            context.SaveChanges();            
        }
```

Comment: Poderia explicar qual o seu problema? Apenas adiantando, o **Fluent API** não tem ligação.

Comment: Como faço para popular a tabela `TBMenuPerfil`? Assim como fiz com as tabelas `TBPerfil` e `TBMenu` usando os recursos que o método **Seed** oferece ?

Comment: Abandonar a Fluent API é uma opção?

Answer (score 1):

A tabela TBMenuPerfil é uma tabela auxiliar. O Entity Framework manipula ela internamente. Você só vai manipular os seus models, como sempre. Mas você precisa pegar o objeto após ele ter sido adicionado ao DbSet

Método para adicionar e recuperar os objetos:

```
public static T AddNew<T>(this EfDbContext context, T entity)
    where T : class
{
    var dbSet = context.Set<T>();

    dbSet.Add(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

Seed:

```
private TBPerfil Perfil1 { get;set; }
private TBPerfil Perfil2 { get;set; }    

this.Perfil1 = this.Context.AddNew(new TBPerfil 
{
    PerfilID=1, Nome="Administrador"
};
this.Perfil2 = this.Context.AddNew(new TBPerfil 
{
    PerfilID=2, Nome="Operacional"
};

private TBMenu Menu1 {get;set;}

    this.Menu1 = this.Context.AddNew(new TBMenu 
    {
        TBMenuID=1, 
        Action="#", 
        Controller=string.Empty, 
        Icon="fui-user", 
        Nome="Cadastros", 
        Posicao=0, 
        Tooltip="Cadastros"
        Perfis = new List<TBPerfil>
        {
            this.Perfil1,
            this.Perfil2
        }
    }

context.SaveChanges();
```